# Select2 plugin in ngx-smart-modal doesn't work

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, jquery-select2

I'm using select2 plugin for my selects in an angular project. When I add my dropdown component in the form or in bootstrap modal, everything work as expected. But I decided to use [ngx-smart-modal](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2yx5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) and when I add the same component in this modal, it does not work. Actually it looks that it removes the span tag of select2.

here the link [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-l2yx5m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue don't come from the library but from the component code itself:

```
onModalOpen() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.js-example-inside').select2({
        placeholder: "inside modal"
      });
    });
  }
```

You need to trigger (with `setTimeout` in my example) a new [Angular check cycle (lifecycle hooks)](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) to wait for the modal content to be displayed and available in the DOM. The element you try to target with `select2(...)` wasn't yet available, that's why it wasn't working.

So the fixed code looks like:

```
  onModalOpen() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $('.js-example-inside').select2({
        placeholder: "inside modal"
      });
    });
  }
```

Here's **[the fixed stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3lea22)**.

Comment: You are the best and made my day! :)

Comment: Hello @Maxime. I updated my stackblitz with a new select component. The problem is that anytime I open the modal, the component would be initialized. When I used a bootstrap modal it was just init once. How can I solve this problem to init the component just once and not everytime I open the modal?

Comment: Hello @Amin, I'm glad it solved your issue! :) To answer your last comment, you need to understand that, in `ngx-smart-modal`, by default, modal content is remove from the DOM each time the modal is closed. So each time you're opening it again, it has to re-initialize each component inside. You need to just "hide" the modal and not "close" it in order to avoid re-initializing your select each time.